# verification fails due to characters after data class name starting with @ failing tests

Tags: mockk

Not sure what they mean at all but my tests fail with something like the following:

```
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: CallHandler(#1).handleSingleCall(eq(CallInfo@f5b7b13))). No matching calls found.

Calls to same method:
1) CallHandler(#1).handleSingleCall(CallInfo@73128b3a)
2) CallHandler(#1).handleSingleCall(CallInfo@7fdcccd5)
```

the line is:

```
coVerify { callHandlerMock.handleSingleCall(callInfo) }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want to verify that `handleSingleCall` of `callHandlerMock` is called with a specific `CallInfo`. The failure message tells you that the desired call did not happen, but the function was called with two other parameters.

It might help to give `CallInfo` a nice descriptive `toString` implementation such that the output is not `CallInfo@73128b3a` but something more helpful that tells you why you have this unexpected result.

The fact that there is no proper `toString` may also mean that there is no proper `equals` in `CallInfo`, and thus, two `CallInfo`s are only considered equal when they are the same instance. Then every verification with an `eq` matcher will fail against some object that is not exactly the same instance that is used inside your unit under test.